# Can't run Jedis example: JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm trying the Jedis (Redis for Java) "Basic usage example" from https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started
but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I'm trying this on OSX 10.9.2 with Jedis-2.4.2, commons-pool2-2.0

Answer (score 11):

Had the same trouble.  All the tutorials online show just running some simple Java BUT you need to have the redis server running on your computer (duh...).  As a noobie I thought it all came in the jar but it does not.  It is a database just like Mongo or whatever.  Try this:

[redis download](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads)

After you download, unzip it into the UserApps  folder (on windows) and then run redis-server.exe.  A window will pop up with the port and such in it.  Then run your java.  Bam, works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You will get this because either you don't have redis running or you're trying to connect to it on the wrong host/port.

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved this problem by downloading Redis setup from https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases and simply installing it. Its more simple and suggested on Redis Download page.

Latest stable release is 2.8.2104

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine for me:
Installing and starting the redis server at localhost:6379

- Install

```
$ wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.2.12.tar.gz 
$ tar xzf redis-2.2.12.tar.gz 
$ cd redis-2.2.12 
$ make
$ make install
```

- Start

$/usr/local/bin/redis-server

from
http://reistiago.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/installing-on-redis-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

eh.this problem i had also came across. Because start the redis server on cmd and store some keys into it.and then i close the server and change to Eclipse tutorial about redis then get such exceptions.
**solutions:**
you can just go to the redis directory in CMD and input "redis-server.exe redis.conf" to start the server. then rerun your previous application in eclipse and it will be ok!